# Should it be this or that?

Tags: grammar

Here's part of a script I'm writing:

(Two men are talking)

Phil: You think I'm the owner of this place? I just clean the place, that's all.

**This**/**That** information seems to disarm the man.

I'm pretty sure it should be "this", is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Using *this* makes it seem more alive, as though you were standing right there in the middle of the action. Using *that* is more detached, as though you were reporting from a neutral standpoint.

But either of them would be possible, just a difference in emphasis.